# Import excel csv data using apex class

Tags: apex, data, csv, import

I have an excel file with a lot of records, and I need to import these records to a salesforce object by **implementing a class and a visualforce page** in order to use it in the future if needed. So, I don't need to work with **data loader** or **import wizard**

Is it possible to do that ? or should I stick with Data Loader ?

Comment: Is it the .xls, .xlsx, or .csv form of the data you are trying to import? Does your data have embedded line feeds?

Comment: Yes, it's a csv file. About the data, no it has no embedded line feeds @KeithC

Answer (score 5):

Providing the CSV files are not too big, you can use a Visualforce [apex:inputFile](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputFile.htm) to upload the file and then apply this [Parse a CSV with Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Code_Samples#Parse_a_CSV_with_APEX) sample code to grab the data from the rows.

If the CSV files are large you will hit a [governor limit](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm) such as the the 6M byte heap space or the 10 seconds of CPU or the 10,000 rows of DML.

Comment: It is actually quite easy to hit the governor limits with either wide or long CSV files. I would recommend planning for a batch process to process a large file.

Comment: it's actually a big file "32,000 record". Could I separate the file into 4 files and use the first way ?

Comment: @HasanKhatib As Jeremy mentions the width - how many columns/characters per line also matters. But yes you could break the file up into pieces.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `<apex:inputFile>` to upload file, then you can use apex to parse input file. For more details you can check following link:

[Import csv file using apex visualforce](http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/import-csv-file-using-apex-visualforce/)

http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/import-csv-file-using-apex-visualforce/

Answer (score 0):

The article [Importing large CSV files via Batch Apex](http://developer.financialforce.com/customizations/importing-large-csv-files-via-batch-apex/) can be useful when the CSV is large. It splits the CSV into iterable lines and the processes them as a batch using [Marty Y. Chang's IETF RFC 4180-compliant CSV Reader.](http://frombelvideres4thfloor.blogspot.co.nz/2010/10/ietf-rfc-4180-compliant-csv-reader-for.html)

This approach can help when keep within the heap size limits.